# Using exim to delete emails via a whitelist

Tags: linux, email, exim

I have a whitelist of emails that I want to keep in my mail queue as I've got a lot of spam from unauthorized email addresses that were added from a recent intrusion. How would I go about using exim to find the emails that don't match my whitelist and to remove them from the queue?

Comment: I think that this question better fits SuperUser.com, doesn't it?

Comment: It may require some scripting or it may be a one-liner. Just very new to using exim and working on a production device and could use some help. If it is a better fit for superuser or serverfault, please assist me in getting it to where it needs to go.

Answer (score 2):

Well, most modern MTAs have built-in capabilities to apply some anti-spamming techniques and/or use some anti-spamming services like RBL. You may check e.g. this doc to get started http://www.maretmanu.org/homepage/inform/exim-spam.php.

If you need to manage the queue "ad-hoc", then there're `exiqgrep -f [user]@domain` command to search for a specific sender in the queue, `exiqgrep -r [user]@domain` for a specific recipient and `exim -Mrm <message-id>` to remove a message w/ a specific Message-Id from the queue. See more at http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/mail/exim-management

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I'm currently trying to delete emails that are sitting in the queue waiting to go out. We've frozen the queue so no more emails are allowed to go out and have isolated the main problem. Now we just need to empty the queue of the illegal senders.

Comment: Thank you for the exim management reference. I think that's what I need to get me in the right direction.